# CodenameOne set indexing of fields for virtual keyboard

Tags: codenameone

Using CodenameOne,
I have a Form that the user needs to fill in. All of the components, however, are actually Containers that represent custom functionality. As an example, I would have a `TextField` alongside a `Button` on a `Container`, and I would use that `Container` as a "`Component`". This allows me to create more advanced functionality by combining existing `Components`.
A good example of where this is necessary is that of a custom date entry field existing out of 3 `TextFields` or a combination of `TextFields` and `ComboBoxes`.

I have a "Field" that has functionality for that of a Contact `Component`.
[image: ContactsComponent]

This all serves as a single "Unit" in order to allow the user to choose a contact or fill in their own. `Buttons` open `Dialog` popups, etc.

My problems comes with when the user uses the Android keyboard. Should this Contact `Object` be the second "Field" and the user presses the 'Next' button on the Android keyboard, the App does not know what field to give focus.
Furthermore, If one of the fields are a `ComboBox` or a `Button` and the user presses next to reach that `Component`, the keyboard doesn't close, and instead removes the 'Next' button, replacing it with a return button or an emoticon selector.

Below is an example situation:
[image: Form Example]

The user would press on the first field, the Keyboard shows up, and when the user presses next, the keyboard's Next button dissapears, as the immediate next field happens to be a `Button` or `ComboBox`.

Is there a way to change the focusing index, or omit certain fields form ever gaining focus in this way? I tried making the entire thing a `Component` but that doesnt allow me to combine other `Components`. Even if it is possible to make the parent `Container` a `Component`, how would I solve this particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is to use the "next focus down" for this functionality so just use `setNextFocusDown(nextTextField)` on each one of the components. Notice that a `ComboBox` won't work as expected although you might want to change that to an `AutoCompleteTextField` which would.

Comment: This does not seem have had any effect. I tried addin nextFocusDown on both the `Container` and `Form` level, to no avail.

Comment: Invoke this on the text fields to indicate the next text field for each one